# Trouble setting up Lenovo IdeaCentre K450 usb boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I am having trouble setting up a Lenovo IdeaCentre K450 to dual boot. I am using a 64-bit 12.04 bootable usb thumb drive (which I have used to boot from many times before).

My Bios boot settings are:

```
CSM -> Enabled
Boot Mode ->Auto
Boot Priority -> Legacy first
Quick Boot -> Enabled
```

and under `Primary Boot Sequence`, all the USB devices are before the hard drives. When inserting the thumb drive and starting the machine, it starts into Win8, as if nothing has happened. When switching the `Boot Priority` to `UEFI first`, the same thing happens. Interestingly, when I disabled `Quick Boot` the PC would beep on booting, and then proceed to boot in Win8 as normal. Any ideas?

thanks!

Nikos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ***DO NOT ATTEMPT TO INSTALL LINUX IN BIOS/CSM/LEGACY MODE ON A SYSTEM IN WHICH WINDOWS IS BOOTING IN EFI/UEFI MODE!!!!*** In other words, setting "CSM" to "Enabled" and "Boot Priority" to "Legacy first" is the *wrong* thing to do! I realize that a lot of sites advise doing this, but they're *wrong.* Using a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot will clear an initial hurdle, but it will put up two or three more down the road, so it creates more problems than it solves. People who advise doing it the hard way don't realize what they're doing because they do eventually clear those later hurdles, but they don't associate them with their initial mistake. (That said, there are some cases where using a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation is the way to go, but they're the exception, not the rule.)

You should probably disable the "quick boot" option; this option often skips some or all of USB initialization, which renders USB devices unbootable. That's probably the immediate cause of your problem. Speaking of "quick boot" options, another one is at least as important: There's an option in Windows called "Fast Startup" or "Hybrid Boot" that you *must* disable, as described [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

On some computers, you may need to hit a function key (or sometimes Esc) just after powering on the computer in order to get a boot menu that enables you to boot from an external device. Unfortunately, the key you use to get this menu varies from one computer to another.

For more in EFI-mode booting, I recommend you read at least one of the following pages:

- [My page on EFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on the same topic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- [Adam Williamson's blog on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I had no luck so far. I disabled Fast Startup and Quick Boot, but the PC keeps booting into Win8, albeit more slowly. Also tried getting directly into the boot sequence (F12 upon boot) and made sure it has the USB on top of the list - again to no avail. It seems others are having [other issues](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/01/08/an-attempt-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-13-10-and-windows-8-on-a-lenovo-ideacenter-k450/) with dual boot on K450. Next is burn an installation cd and try from that.

Comment: Well, the answer was embarrassingly simple. I was using a corrupt usb stick. Created a new one and the PC boots perfectly fine from the USB. Disabling Fast Startup was key, though.